# AWS IOT JS device SDK not connecting and keep on reconnecting again and again

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-iot

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var device = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: "<path>-private.pem.key",
    certPath: "<path>-certificate.pem.crt",
    caPath: "<path>-root-CA.key",
    clientId: uuid.v4(),
    debug:true,
    host: <hostId>,
    will:{
        topic:"blahblahblah",
        payload:"disconnecting",
        qos:0,
        retain:false
    }
});

device
    .on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connect');
        device.subscribe('cgw/devices/register');
    });

device.on('message', (topic, payload, message) => {
    console.log(topic);
    console.log(payload);
    console.log(message);
});

   device
      .on('close', function() {
         console.log('close');
      });
   device
      .on('reconnect', function() {
         console.log('reconnect');
      });
   device
      .on('offline', function() {
         console.log('offline');
      });
   device
      .on('error', function(error) {
         console.log('error', error);
      });
```

I am trying to run the sample code above but the device is not getting connected. I have also tried passing

> retain param as false

as per https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/issues/61

but still the program is not running and shows

offline
close
reconnecting
close
reconnecting
close
reconnecting
close
reconnecting

Comment: Guys, I found the answer. The policy ARN attached to certificates should contain

  "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Connect"
      ],

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the policy assigned to the identity/device does not provide correct access to the AWS IoT broker. So, in order to connect, publish, subscribe and receive data from AWS broker the corresponding policy should contain the following statements:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": [
        "PUT YOU CLIENT RESOURCE HERE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": [
        "PUT YOUR TOPIC RESOURCE HERE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": [
        "PUT YOUR TOPIC/FILTER RESOURCE HERE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": [
        "PUT YOUR TOPIC RESOURCE HERE"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```